# How to connect to .GIT projects through Adobe Dreamwaver

Tags: git, repository, gitlab, dreamweaver

i want connect to a gitlab project 
https://gitlab.com/online98/smndr.git

How i can connected to it through Adobe Dreamwaver

thanks.

Comment: Gitlab knows nothing about Dreamwaver: you have to get dreamweaver to talk to gitlab, which is done through regular git protocol like on github and any other git frontend.

Comment: First learn git from the command line, and how to use it on gitlab and github, then understand what Dreamweaver does with Git.